# QGIS v. ArcMap Network Analysis Isochrones

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, isochrone, network-analysis

I am looking at developing catchment areas based on a street-lines feature class against various bus stops to find an ideal catchment area which can then be converted and run in a simulation. The impedance is distance over time such that a vehicle will only make it so far, by x-time. The images below show a 5,10,15-minute area. The visual aesthetic of the ArcMap representation is a bit shoddy but I just wanted to have something for comparison.

In ArcMap I am able to control the speed attribute for the network impedance using attribute table values in the Network Analysis extension. I need to somehow control QGIS interaction with the road network to 25 mph if that's possible.

- QGIS Plugin ORS Tools (previously OSM Tools) only allows for an input classification such as 'driving-car' in the Isochrones generation filed under the Batch Jobs tab. I need to limit the speeds of the road network to 25 mph and I have not found a good way of doing this.

Comparisons shown below are using the same point in the City of San Jose, California. The QGIS image shows the point in red. I forgot to make the point visible in ArcMap. The ArcMap image is different because it is able to control for the street-speeds.

I have done several forms of research on this topic and ORS was the one tool/plugin that seemed to accomplish what I was looking for.

How can I set the speed to 25 mph using QGIS?

ArcMap

[image]

QGIS with ORS

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our 'Focused question/Best answer' model operates, and which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] the question to focus on your most pressing issue.  Once you get a better read on how we operate, you can ask the other questions as separate Questions.